# Recording a network stream using VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming, recording

I am trying to capture a video network stream and save it in a file. I have found a couple of articles on how to do that using VLC, but none of them worked. All of them used the procedure outlined in this previous question: [How to record a mp3/m3u stream using VLC?](https://superuser.com/questions/156474/how-to-record-a-mp3-m3u-stream-using-vlc)

However, when I attempt to either stream to a file or convert a stream to a file, the only thing I get is an empty `.mp4` file. When streaming it directly to the file, VLC instead start displaying the stream locally (despite having this option turned off).

I also found [this related thread](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=145211) which suggests that this might be a bug of VLC itself; however, browsing through the ticket I was unable to find what the cause of this is and what a possible way to resolve it could look like.

Is there currently a way to capture a video network stream to a file? If VLC can't do this I am happy to try something else.

Just a heads up: I am not trying to rip copyrighted material; there is a conference that is streaming it's talks, but the interesting talks take place in times where I can't attend them, so I would like to record them for seeing them the next day.

Comment: You might want to look into simply using `ffmpeg` directly. You may need to know what kind of stream they are running to get everything working correctly but its not unlikely that you can simply look at the stream URL to figure out how the stream is being broadcast.